# Do we complicate database tables with non-TEXT columns?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design

So far in my experience, every piece of data saved inside table's columns did not have a specific reason to be integer or boolean or so on. Yet again, we all are advised to use column type based on the data type. And I have been doing so for years now.

I am thinking to completely drop this idea and to use tables only with TEXT columns. It's easier to create them (don't have to write type but can copy/paste TEXT), compiler will warn me when type conversion is needed, and dozens of reasons like these ones.

Is there a good non-beatable reason why I should not switch to this practice?

Comment: This is a really, really bad idea. How do you prevent someone storing `foobar` in a column where you expect a number? Or `46476-77-59` in a column where you expect a date? If you are going to answer "My application is taking care of that" then you are fooling yourself. There is no way you can control every way data gets into the database. I have seen **many** database where the people claimed the application would take care of doing that - and it didn't. And I'm not even talking about databases that were used from multiple applications.

Comment: And no: the "compiler" won't warn you when someone writes `insert into my_table (some_number_column) values ('one hundred twenty five');`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OK, so obviously this cannot be applied in every case. But what about the applications which deal only with JSON/XML data sent from API? There is no user interaction here.

Comment: maybe you just need some more experience.  there are tons of reasons.  unfortunately voting to close this one as opinion based.

Comment: @Randy You may be right. Database design is not my close field. But I do it almost each time as part of programming tasks. And as I said to Michael, maybe I indeed forgot the rule of not inventing the wheel.

Comment: Let me just offer a slightly philosophical point of view... "type" is a pair, comprised from two sets. One set contains all **values** valid for that type, and the other contains all **operations** valid on these values. By using a wrong type, there is nothing to stop a buggy application from using values that may be inappropriate for what you are trying to achieve, or performing operations that make no sense or would corrupt the data (further). You may think you'll be able to enforce proper values and operations in your code, but no human has been born yet able to write bug-free code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No we don't complicate database tables with non-TEXT columns, instead we make the database provide a consistent format for the storge of the data.

By using number, boolean and date fields we get all the wonderful validation and retrieval methods that the database has implemented for these fields.

Without using the specific datatypes we will start reinventing the wheel when we need validations and specific display formats.

I once worked in a data warehouse group and it frequently made me want to have better defined datatypes, formats, required fields and validations on most of the data received.

Comment: But this approach can be used for specific database design. Do you agree on this? When you don't need such validation or there is no user input interaction. Does this mean we cannot exclude this as bad idea in ALL cases?

Comment: No.  But ALL doesn't reflect the world I've worked in for a decades.  I avoid absolutes and rules.  There certainly are cases where a more 'raw storage' approach is suitable and for those key-value stores like mongoDB are appropriate.  I would try to pick the data storage approach that matches your business need (not defined here) rather than bending a certain storage mechanism such as a rdbms to your needs.

Comment: It seems that I've forgotten the golden rule "Don't invent the wheel". :) So I will continue designing databases with ad-hoc approach. When unsure, I'll just stick to the wheel.